# Assigning onkeyup event to multiple objects at once

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am working with qualtrics and I am trying to customize  their matrix control. I am trying to loop through a matrix with 8 rows and 4 columns where each cell contains a textbox and assign each textbox an onkeyup event like so:

```
for (var j=1; j< 9; j++){
        row_txt[j] = [];
        for (var k=1; k<5; k++){
            txt1= $('QR~QID2~'+j+'~'+k);
            txt1.onkeyup=function(){alert(j+','+k);};
        }
}
```

However, the onkeyup event returns "9,5" for each textbox changed. Why isn't it displaying the correct indices? How can I assign the same onkeyup event to multiple objects with the corresponding parameters j and k ?

Thank you

Comment: You should just attach one event to the container, and use `event.target` to find the textarea that triggered it. Research event delegation.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - you can only use delegation if you don't intend to override the default behavior (e.g. block some keys, apply transformations, etc...).  We don't know what they're actually intending to do in their event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the value of `j` and `k` is that the actual keyup event occurs sometime in the future.  When that event occurs, the values of `j` and `k` have gotten to the end of the `for` loop and thus all event handlers will show the same values.

The usual way to fix this is by adding a closure that freezes the values of `j` and `k` separately for each event handler.

```
for (var j=1; j< 9; j++){
    row_txt[j] = [];
    for (var k=1; k<5; k++){
        (function(j, k) {
            txt1= $('QR~QID2~'+j+'~'+k);
            txt1.onkeyup=function(){alert(j+','+k);};
        })(j, k);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm curious what you're doing with this:

```
$('QR~QID2~'+j+'~'+k);
```

That will create something like this:

```
$('QR~QID2~1~9);
```

Are you actually using HTML tags with that tagname or should this be a class name or an id (e.g prefaced with a `.` or `#`)?

Comment: Wow, and I thought I was bad when it comes to answering duplicates XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - yes it is a duplicate in concept.  But, the challenge for people who have this particular problem is that they often don't know how to take someone else's solution and apply it exactly to their code in their problem. That's why I sometimes offer to apply it their situation.

Comment: $('QR~QID2~1~9); is the Id of the textbox inside a cell of the matrix

Comment: Onkeyup I'm trying to re-add the total for the row for which one of the cells was changed. I am new to js so I didn't really know what to look up. I will check out delegation and the answer for the question I might have duplicated

Comment: @ivan, if it's an id, then you need `#` in front of it for the CSS selector unless you're using some homemade `$` function that isn't taking a CSS selector.

Comment: Yes thank you, I know. That is qualtrics selector apparently.

Comment: it worked like a charm, thank you. i will read up on closures in js now